# In Firefox, iFrame html loads without the jquery, jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

I have this website: [www.paidly.co](http://www.paidly.co)
In it there is an iFrame like so

```
<iframe class="iphone-content" src="Mobile/main.html"> </iframe>
```

which calls this doc

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paidly</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> ... </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome and IE but in Firefox only the body is loaded. The calls to the CDN are apparently not taking place. There are also no errors shown in the Developers console. All works perfectly fine when I reload the frame, or open it in a new tab.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the errors you can see on the console?

Comment: @MelanciaUK There is no error shown, none at all. I do get this warning 
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Comment: So it looks like your problem is not exactly on the bits posted. It's on the Javascript bits.

Comment: But there is no Javascript, other than the JQuery, and JQuery mobile.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you are building an iframe for facebook app, you may have codes outside your own server... aka the ones from jquery and jquery mobile is outside the domain.. hence not loaded. Pull them in your folder and reference it hence  and you probably will be fine